# If all corporate (large scale) networks need switches

Tags: switch

In learning about networking, I am wondering if switches are *required* for large-scale networks, or if there are alternatives to them that solve the same or similar problems they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you could build an entire network with routed (L3) links, using routers instead of switches. Practically, switches are a better choice, much cheaper and usually faster.

Comment: But I'm still wondering if you for sure always need switches, like even in a cloud data center, or if it is virtualized or replaced by something else.

Comment: You don't always require switches, but the combination of switching and routing makes a network scale better, and you've asked about large-scale networks. Of course, switches and routers can also be virtualized but you do require the functionality. I'd suggest you get a decent book on networking (sorry, no recommendations here) and discover the basics before tackling large-scale and virtual networks.